# Lounge access on arrival at Singapore airport Terminal 2

Tags: singapore, lounges, prioritypass

I will be arriving at Singapore airport terminal 2 at 3:00 am in the morning and my hotel doesn't allow me early check-in. I have a priority pass. Will I be able to access the Lounge on arrival?

Comment: Note that in Changi, contrary to many other international airports, all arriving passengers get to the departure area (there is no separate arrivals area), so you can get access to any of the departure lounges. Whether they do accept you on arrival with Priority Pass is however unclear in my opinion (except for the explicitly named "Arrivals Lounge" below of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was at the Singapore airport today and was allowed the entry at the Ambassador Transit Lounge in terminal 2 with no issues whatsoever. The guy at the reception did not even bother checking the boarding pass and **He told me that they always take people in holding the PP**.

I don't know about the other lounges but you can always go to 'The Haven' arrivals lounge if you are denied entry.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Review: ‘The Haven’ Arrivals Lounge – Singapore T3](https://mainlymiles.com/2018/02/25/review-the-haven-arrivals-lounge-singapore-t3/)

as a Priority Pass holder:

> **Priority Pass**, **LoungeKey**, **LoungePass** and **DragonPass** all get 3 hours
>   access, including access to shower facilities, but not the nap rooms.

and

> Priority Pass will get 20% off nap room rates (others vary, call for
>   more information).

The link mentions how to get to this location if you are arriving on a flight - thus implying you can use it when you arrive.